# HTML video not playing on mobile after multiple visits from same phone

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mobile-safari

I've run into a strange problem with video playback on mobile - in general, the videos playback fine on phones, but if the same phone has visited the site more than a few times (say 4 or 5), the video will no longer play and instead display a still image. Here is the format of the HTML for the videos:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="waterBackground" src="../assets/water1-forwards_compressed.mp4"></video>
```

There is one line of JS changing the video playback rate, but that's it:

```
$("#waterBackground")[0].playbackRate = 0.8;
```

All of the HTML videos use this exact format, and every phone I have tested this on (except iphone < 5) has no trouble playing the first the first few times. But things stop working after that. When I clear the browser history and close and reopen the app, the video is working again. Any ideas why this might be happening and how I can fix it?